# batching of events google pub/sub and then publishing a collection as single event - apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I am trying to batch events using google pub/sub I see that I can set microbatches based on fixed windows batch size etc. However I want to send the result as a collection of messages - so a) batch the events and send results of the batch as a single event - Do I need a custom transformation or is there a capability from apache beam that will allow me to do that.

Comment: Do you want to listen the PubSub permanently? I mean in the streaming mode and to build windows of X minutes. In each windows, you want to pack the messages and post a new PubSub message with all the packed messages, in only one. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: For future readers: it looks like you have posted a more detailed question about doing this in an Apache Beam pipeline here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379467/apache-beam-using-pcollections-to-window-batch-pack-events-to-consumer